# Add data in NSMutableArray from for loop

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have a for loop where I can obtain retrieved data from an imported file.

```
-(NSArray *) csvArray2CompaniesArray:(NSArray *) csvArray
{
    int i=0;

    NSMutableArray *ma = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSArray * row in csvArray)
    {
        if (i>0)
        {
            Company *_company = [[Company alloc] init];

            _company.name = [row objectAtIndex:0];
            _company.address = [row objectAtIndex:1];
            _company.telephone = [row objectAtIndex:2];

            [ma addObject:_company];

            //[_companyAddress addObject:[row objectAtIndex:1]];
            //[_companyAddress addObject:_company.address];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (NSArray *) ma;   
}
```

I would like to save the data generated in the loop in a global NSMutableArray that I created called "companyAddress"
I tried with

```
[_companyAddress addObject:[row objectAtIndex:1]];
```

or

```
[_companyName addObject:_company.address];
```

when I try to print on the screen the contents of _companyAddress it just outputs the last line contained from "_company.address" so I suppose the data in the NSMutableArray is overwritten for each loop instead of being added.

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to add data properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand...where are you "printing to screen"?  Show us that code.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine ... it must be something with the way you print the contents of the array

Comment: I just try to print the contents in -(void) viewDidLoad with NSLog(@"%@", _companyAddress) but I just receive 1 line out of 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray companyAddress` //gobal declaration with property and synthesize plus allocation in `application` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in Application Delegate

Now create `Application Delegate's` object say something like your  Application Delegate name is

```
AppDelegate then AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

The method will be :

```
-(void) csvArray2CompaniesArray:(NSArray *) csvArray
{

 for (NSArray * row in csvArray)
 {
        Company *_company = [[Company alloc] init];

        _company.name = [row objectAtIndex:0];
        _company.address = [row objectAtIndex:1];
        _company.telephone = [row objectAtIndex:2];

        [objAppDelegate.companyAddress addObject:_company];
        [_company release];

 }
  NSLog(@"%@",objAppDelegate.companyAddress);
}
```

All company references will be stored in gobal companyAddress mutablearray

**EDIT** : just highlighted text for better answer

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Is there any way to do it without needing to touch the AppDelegate?

Comment: use companyAddress as class memeber in .h of your view controller then replace  [objAppDelegate.companyAddress addObject:_company]; with
[companyAddress addObject:_company];

Comment: Doing the NSLog outside the loop it outputs 30 lines but all of them are (null). How can this be?

Comment: check your csvArray has value and row array you are using has value

Comment: Hi, one question. Why do you do the "Company *_company = [[Company alloc] init];" on every cycle of the loop? Isn't the initialization something we can do just once or is there a reason/benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: You mean init every time? then each object intialized is stored in nsmutablearray for further use. If why _company? then its variable name as user has used in question so i have used same name.